# Error al conectar impresora Bluetooth Andoid Studio

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Soy nuevo en la programando en android studio, estoy generando una interfaz para conectar una impresora Bluetooh con ayuda del SDK de ejemplo incluido pero al momento de llamar al metodo que realizara la conexion me genera el siguiente error, algun experto que me pudiera orientar.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: mx.prodeco.printnew, PID: 4653
                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void net.posprinter.posprinterface.IMyBinder.connectBtPort(java.lang.String, net.posprinter.posprinterface.UiExecute)' on a null object reference
                                                                   at mx.prodeco.printnew.MainActivity.connetBle(MainActivity.java:213)
                                                                   at mx.prodeco.printnew.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:124)
                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5647)
                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22462)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6361)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
```

este es el código:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    public static String DISCONNECT="com.posconsend.net.disconnetct";

    //IMyBinder interface，All methods that can be invoked to connect and send data are encapsulated within this interface
    public static IMyBinder binder;

    //bindService connection
    ServiceConnection conn= new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
            //Bind successfully
            binder= (IMyBinder) iBinder;
            Log.e("binder","connected");
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            Log.e("disbinder","disconnected");
        }
    };

    public static boolean ISCONNECT;
    Button BTCon,//connection button
            BTDisconnect,//disconnect button
            BtposPrinter,
            BtSb;// start posprint button
    EditText showET;// show edittext
    CoordinatorLayout container;

    private View dialogView;
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;

    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1
            ,adapter2;
    private ListView lv1,lv2;
    private ArrayList<String> deviceList_bonded=new ArrayList<String>();//bonded list
    private ArrayList<String> deviceList_found=new ArrayList<String>();//found list
    private Button btn_scan; //scan button
    private LinearLayout LLlayout;
    AlertDialog dialog;
    String mac;
    int pos ;

    private DeviceReceiver myDevice;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("bluetooth", "onCreate...");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //bind service，get ImyBinder object
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,PosprinterService.class);
        bindService(intent, conn, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        //init view
        initView();

        //setlistener
        setlistener();
    }

    private void initView(){
        Log.i("bluetooth", "initView...");
        BTCon= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonConnect);
        BTDisconnect= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDisconnect);

        BtposPrinter= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPosPrinter);

        BtSb= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSB);
        showET= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.showET);

    }

    private void setlistener(){
        Log.i("bluetooth", "setlistener...");
        BTCon.setOnClickListener(this);
        BTDisconnect.setOnClickListener(this);
        BtSb.setOnClickListener(this);
        //BTpos.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.i("bluetooth", "onClick...");
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.buttonConnect:{
                //bluetooth connection
                connetBle();
                break;
            }
            case R.id.buttonSB:{
                setBluetooth();
                BTCon.setText(getString(R.string.connect));
                break;
            }
            case R.id.buttonDisconnect:{
                if (ISCONNECT){
                    binder.disconnectCurrentPort(new UiExecute() {
                        @Override
                        public void onsucess() {
                            showSnackbar(getString(R.string.toast_discon_success));
                            showET.setText("");
                            BTCon.setText(getString(R.string.connect));
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onfailed() {
                            showSnackbar(getString(R.string.toast_discon_faile));

                        }
                    });
                }else {
                    showSnackbar(getString(R.string.toast_present_con));
                }
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }





    }
    private void connetBle(){
        Log.i("bluetooth", "connetBle...");
        String bleAdrress=showET.getText().toString();
        Log.i("bluetooth", ""+bleAdrress+"...");
        if (bleAdrress.equals(null)||bleAdrress.equals("")){
            showSnackbar(getString(R.string.bleselect));
        }else {
            binder.connectBtPort(bleAdrress, new UiExecute() {
                @Override
                public void onsucess() {
                    ISCONNECT=true;
                    showSnackbar(getString(R.string.con_success));
                    BTCon.setText(getString(R.string.con_success));

                    binder.write(DataForSendToPrinterPos80.openOrCloseAutoReturnPrintState(0x1f), new UiExecute() {
                        @Override
                        public void onsucess() {
                            binder.acceptdatafromprinter(new UiExecute() {
                                @Override
                                public void onsucess() {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onfailed() {
                                    ISCONNECT=false;
                                    showSnackbar(getString(R.string.con_has_discon));
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onfailed() {

                        }
                    });


                }

                @Override
                public void onfailed() {

                    ISCONNECT=false;
                    showSnackbar(getString(R.string.con_failed));
                }
            });
        }


    }
    public void setBluetooth(){
        Log.i("bluetooth", "setBluetooth...");
        bluetoothAdapter=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
            //open bluetooth
            Intent intent=new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, Conts.ENABLE_BLUETOOTH);
        }else {

            showblueboothlist();

        }
    }
    private void showblueboothlist() {
        Log.i("bluetooth", "showbluetoothlist...");
        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
        }
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(this);
        dialogView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.printer_list, null);
        adapter1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, deviceList_bonded);
        lv1=(ListView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        btn_scan=(Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btn_scan);
        LLlayout=(LinearLayout) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.ll1);
        lv2=(ListView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.listView2);
        adapter2=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, deviceList_found);
        lv1.setAdapter(adapter1);
        lv2.setAdapter(adapter2);
        dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("BLE").setView(dialogView).create();
        dialog.show();

        myDevice=new DeviceReceiver(deviceList_found,adapter2,lv2);

        //register the receiver
        IntentFilter filterStart=new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        IntentFilter filterEnd=new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        registerReceiver(myDevice, filterStart);
        registerReceiver(myDevice, filterEnd);

        setDlistener();
        findAvalibleDevice();
    }
    private void setDlistener() {
        Log.i("bluetooth", "setDlistener...");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        btn_scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                LLlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //btn_scan.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        //boned device connect
        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    if(bluetoothAdapter!=null&&bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
                        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

                    }

                    String msg=deviceList_bonded.get(arg2);
                    mac=msg.substring(msg.length()-17);
                    String name=msg.substring(0, msg.length()-18);
                    //lv1.setSelection(arg2);
                    dialog.cancel();
                    showET.setText(mac);
                    //Log.i("TAG", "mac="+mac);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        //found device and connect device
        lv2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    if(bluetoothAdapter!=null&&bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
                        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

                    }
                    String msg=deviceList_found.get(arg2);
                    mac=msg.substring(msg.length()-17);
                    String name=msg.substring(0, msg.length()-18);
                    //lv2.setSelection(arg2);
                    dialog.cancel();
                    showET.setText(mac);
                    Log.i("TAG", "mac="+mac);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /*
    find avaliable device
     */
    private void findAvalibleDevice() {
        Log.i("bluetooth", "findAvalibleDevice...");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Set<BluetoothDevice> device=bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        deviceList_bonded.clear();
        if(bluetoothAdapter!=null&&bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
            adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        if(device.size()>0){
            //already
            for(Iterator<BluetoothDevice> it = device.iterator(); it.hasNext();){
                BluetoothDevice btd=it.next();
                deviceList_bonded.add(btd.getName()+'\n'+btd.getAddress());
                adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }else{
            deviceList_bonded.add("No can be matched to use bluetooth");
            adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
    /**
     * show the massage
     * @param showstring content
     */
    private void showSnackbar(String showstring){
        Snackbar.make(container, showstring,Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.button_unable)).show();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        binder.disconnectCurrentPort(new UiExecute() {
            @Override
            public void onsucess() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onfailed() {

            }
        });
        unbindService(conn);
    }
}
```

Comment: pfff estaba editando mi respuesta y veo que agregaste una solución, en fin, agregué la razón por la cual no puedes realizar la conexión BLE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se define:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'void
>   net.posprinter.posprinterface.IMyBinder.connectBtPort(java.lang.String,
>   net.posprinter.posprinterface.UiExecute)' on a null object reference

indica que `binder` tiene un valor null al tratar de ejectar su método `connectBtPort()`

```
 binder.connectBtPort(bleAdrress, new UiExecute() {
```

**Revisa si tienes declarado el servicio dentro de tu AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application


    <service android:name="net.posprinter.service.PosprinterService" />


</application>
```

**ya que esto puede provocar la no inicialización del servicio, y el valor de `binder` sería null**, si declaras el servicio, se debe llamar el método `onServiceConnected()` el cual inicializará binder :

```
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder){

        binder = (IMyBinder) iBinder;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Logre resolverlo fue un error propio pase por alto agregar a mi manifest la linea de mi servicio

```
<service android:name="net.posprinter.service.PosprinterService" />
```